# Unstable behaviour of counting inversions algorithm(python)

Tags: python, algorithm

First of all, inversions are pairs of numbers, in a disordered list, where the larger of the two numbers is to the left of smaller number. In the following list: [ 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 ] there are 3 inversions: (3,2), (5,2), and (5,4)

Here is my code of counting inversions:

```
def num_inv(array):
    count = count_left = count_right = 0
    if len(array)<=1:
        return 0

    mid = len(array)//2
    left_array = array[:mid]
    right_array = array[mid:]

    count_left = num_inv(array[:mid])
    count_right = num_inv(array[mid:])


    i = j =  k = 0

    while i < len(left_array) and j < len(right_array):
        if left_array[i] <= right_array[j]:
            array[k] = left_array[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            array[k] = right_array[i]
            j +=1
            count += len(left_array[i:])
        k+=1   


    while i <len(left_array):
        array[k] = left_array[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1


    while j <len(right_array):
        array[k] = right_array[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1


    return count + count_left + count_right
```

In my test cases(most of them) it gives a correct result, but sometimes it's wrong. Can you please have a look and tell me what is wrong with the code? I spent descent amount of time on debugging, so that I need a fresh look at my code.

**Test cases: t4 outputs incorrect result**

```
t1 = [1,3,5,2,4,6]
print("Testing using", t1)
print("Expecting:", 3)
print("Returned:", num_inv(t1))

t2 = [1,5,3,2,4]
print("\nTesting using", t2)
print("Expecting:", 4)
print("Returned:", num_inv(t2))

t3 = [5,4,3,2,1]
print("\nTesting using", t3)
print("Expecting:", 10)
print("Returned:", num_inv(t3))

t4 = [1,6,3,2,4,5]
print("\nTesting using", t4)
print("Expecting:", 5)
print("Returned:", num_inv(t4))

t5 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print("\nTesting using", t5)
print("Expecting:", 0)
print("Returned:", num_inv(t5))
```

Comment: Could you please add some examples of the wrong results?

Comment: @GPhilo Example t4

Comment: What is the **result** you get for that?

Comment: @GPhilo I got 7, but it should be 5

Comment: Ok, can you add to the question an explanation of what you intend as "inversion"? It's needed to understand what your idea behind what the code does was before spotting what te problem is

Comment: @GPhilo Added to the post

Comment: The way to find the problem is to print out diagnostic information that allows you to see the inversions it finds. Look at the result, identify the missing or spurious inversions, and deduce what property it has that your code does not handle properly.

Comment: `array[k] = right_array[i]` looks suspicious (it should be `right_array[j]`). Is it a copy-paste error, or is it coded so?

Comment: @user58697 you are right! But still the result is wrong :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you compare `left_array[i] <= right_array[j]` in your first `while` loop, but then you copy from `right_array[i]`. This has got to be a mistake, but it's not what throws off the counts.

After this correction I added one line to your code, the diagnostic `print()` statement in the first while loop:

```
while i < len(left_array) and j < len(right_array):
    if left_array[i] <= right_array[j]:
        array[k] = left_array[i]
        i+=1
    else:
        array[k] = right_array[j]
        j +=1
        print("Counting as inversions of", array[k], ":", left_array[i:])
        count += len(left_array[i:])
    k+=1
```

I then ran your test `t4`, and got the following output:

```
Testing using [1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5]
Expecting: 5
Counting as inversions of 3 : [6]
Counting as inversions of 2 : [6, 3]
Counting as inversions of 4 : [6, 3]
Counting as inversions of 5 : [6, 3]
Returned: 7
```

Get it? When you find one inverted pair, it is incorrect to assume (as your code does) that the rest of `left_array` consists of inversions (that is, of numbers larger than `array[k]`). Here, 4 and 5 are not inverted with respect to 3. You'll have to count differently.

Comment: Hm...The idea was, that the last two arrays(left and right) are already sorted. So I should correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work.

(It generates the actual inversions and their indices, not just the count.)

```
def find_inversions(arr):
    for i, ival in enumerate(arr):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)):
            jval = arr[j]
            if jval < ival:
                yield (i, j), (ival, jval)


for case, expected in (
    ([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6], 3),
    ([1, 5, 3, 2, 4], 4),
    ([5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 10),
    ([1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5], 5),
    ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 0),
):
    n = len(list(find_inversions(case)))
    print(case, n, expected)
```

outputs

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6] 3 3
[1, 5, 3, 2, 4] 4 4
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 10 10
[1, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5] 5 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 0 0
```

**EDIT:** Here's another approach that isn't O(N^2). It is about 66% faster for e.g. `range(100)`, and 2x faster for `range(500)`.

```
def find_inversions_2(arr):
    seen_indices = defaultdict(set)
    for index, value in enumerate(arr):
        seen_indices[value].add(index)
        for seen_val in seen_indices:
            if seen_val > value:
                for seen_index in seen_indices[seen_val]:
                    yield (seen_index, index), (seen_val, value)
```

Comment: Agree, but you implemented the code with double loop. So it will take O(n^2) running time. I want to use the idea of merge sort, so that the algorithm will be faster

Comment: You might want to have that information in the original post too, then...

Comment: @DY92 I added another approach that isn't O(N^2).

Comment: Well to be fair the OP did not ask for the problem to be reimplemented from scratch, they asked for help spotting the problem.

Comment: Counting inversions on a merge sort is `O(n.log(n))`